# Loop on array javascript show result data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I have a problem in my script.
I have a loop in php who show this in html, this work good :

```
<?php foreach ($locations as $key => $value) : ?>

     <div class="storelocator-info" data-id="<?= $value['codepostal']; ?>" 
           style="display: block;"> 
         <p class="title-depot"><?= $value['name']; ?></p>
   </div>
<?php endforeach ; ?>
```

Now i have a searchbar who i enter a zip code like 11 or 11111 send in ajax in my controller, i return the result in json format like this :

```
try {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            if (data['success'] === false){         

                var index;
                var a = data.zip;
                for (index = 0; index < a.length; ++index) {

                    jQuery('.storelocator-info').hide();
                    jQuery('.storelocator-info[data-id='+a[index]+']').show();
                }

                jQuery('.storelocator-error').hide();
            } else{
                jQuery('.moulinroty-loader').hide();
                jQuery('.storelocator-info').hide();
                jQuery('.storelocator-error').fadeToggle();
            }   
        }
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.log('error' + e);
}
```

data.zip is an array like this ['85000,85001'];
I want to show only "" where data.zip == data-id attribute with javascript or jquery .

the result show only the last result in my array with data-id = 85001,
so i want to show 85000 and 85001

can you explain me where is my mistache or error please?

Thank for help

Comment: Your mistache should be just between your nuse and your muth. Sorry for this

Comment: could be a copy error but `<div class="storelocator-info" data-id="<?= $value['zipdode']; style="display: block;">` is missing a closing tag for php

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding all elements in every iteration of your loop. Hide them before and then show those which need to be shown:

```js
var a = data.zip;
jQuery('.storelocator-info').hide();
for (var index = 0; index < a.length; ++index) {
  jQuery('.storelocator-info[data-id=' + a[index] + ']').show();
}
```